# Establishing month length and first day

Tags: php, date

Is there a simple way of, given a month and a year, establishing:

- <s>How many days there are in that month (factoring in leap years)</s> [Done](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php)
- What day of the week the first day fall upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php

```
$num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2003); // 31
```

and weekdays:

```
$weekday = date("l", mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year));
$print ($weekday);
```

The latter is not very efficient but seems nicer than using getdate:

```
$my_t=getdate(date("U"));
print("$my_t[weekday], $my_t[month] $my_t[mday], $my_t[year]");
```

Output like

```
Wednesday, September 29, 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function, particularly `date('t')` for the number of days in the month (ie the month given in `time()`) and `date('t',$epoch)` for the number of days of the month represented by the timestamp `$epoch` (which, of course, is given in epoch).

And for the day of the week, there's `date('l',$epoch)` (where the first argument is a lower-case `'L'`).

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer to your questions with all needed variables and calculations by going to wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week